# Jquery UI - Tabs reacting weired

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm having a wierd problem with jquery ui tabs.

here's the code:

```
  <div class="ym-gbox">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
            <h1>Versions Übersicht</h1>
    <br />
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">System Kern</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Anwendungen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Bibliotheken</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bordertable">
<tr><th>Name</th><td>System Kern</td></tr>
<tr><th>Version</th><td>1.0.0 </td></tr>
<tr><th>Beschreibung</th><td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">System Kern</td></tr>
<tr><th>Webseite</th><td>http://www.dsws.biz</td></tr>
<tr><th>Lizenz</th><td>Dark Star Web Services Source Lizenz</td></tr>
<tr><th>Autor</th><td>
</td></tr>
</table>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            b
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            c
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As soon as the page loads, the complete page is loaded into the tab tabs.
I don't really have a clue why this happens.

Comment: Do you see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGYDb/)?

Comment: it displays the tabs correct.
But afterwards the homepage is loaded. I'm a little bit confused about this.

Comment: figured out the problem.
I'm using mod-rewrite to mask the php created pages and parameters.

If I remove the href it works. but is soon as they are there, it shows the same behaviour again.

Comment: I moved it to the ajax based version. there it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the core of the problem.
The System does not prevent the default handler from beeing fired.
For Links it is an redirect to the page.
If you add the preventDefault inside of a click handler and handle the click event according to what you want to do (for example change Tab to selected tab) you can bypass this.

example:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});
```

This example is taken from this page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

I had a quite similar problem today.
After adding this code it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me this exact problem was related to the base tag and couldn't be solved by click event Chris idea refers to.  It may also occur if your urls are being rewritten to have the full absolute url, e.g. by a caching tool or .htaccess

So if your tabs were being rewritten as `<a href="http://example.com/page/#tab1">tabname</a>`

Then a solution is to remove the full url before initializing the tabs.  The following (expanded to keep it simple), removes everything leading up to the #

```
jQuery("#mytabs ul li a").each(function () {
    var current = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    var n = current.indexOf("#");
    jQuery(this).attr("href", current.substr(n));
});

jQuery("#mytabs").tabs( .. )
```

Answer (score 3):

As user user2235863 said, you need to delete base tag from the code to make it work. I don't know why it works, but it is.

But this modification can have a side effects like loading relative url images. The solution is delete base tag using javascript after page load and before tabs init:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('base').remove();
    $('#tabs_div').tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am having the same weird problem that the tab is loaded with the complete page. It seems like an infinite loop where the tab content is loaded with the complete page over and over.

This happens using ver. 1.9.2 of jQueryUI and ver. 1.8.3 of jQuery but not in ver. 1.8.17 of jQueryUI and ver. 1.8.3 of jQuery. That's why jsfiddle does not show it.

Chris I am also using a mod_rewrite module but I really need it so it is not an option to skip it nor to use an Ajax-based version.

Comment: I didn't find an other solution then the ajax push. but I'm still looking to find something.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the HTML < base href="http://site_name" / > from your pages. (Base Tags)

I had the same problem and this fixed it for some reason. I'm using ui-1.10.2

Comment: but the problem on this solution is, that if you use rewrite, all images need to be addressed absolute and not relative to an base url

Answer (score 1):

If removing the BASE tag will not work for your site environment (because of URL rewriting or other similar techniques being used) the solution is to generate a variable containing the full URL of the current page and write it to the beginning of your tab HREFs before the #tab-number matching your tab IDs. This way jQuery UI will identify that your tab content is local to the current page and not try to load it via AJAX using the URL stored in the BASE tag. A PHP example would be:

```
$url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off') ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

There may be more complete or accurate ways to get the proper current URL, especially if you are using a load balancer, in the answers to this Stack question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url
```